# number of translate 0 to 1 between 2 point in binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fingerprint, binary-image

I have binary fingerprint image . I want to count the number of transform 1 to 0 between 2 point . the value of two point is 0. Can any bode help me for write `matlab` code of it?

my picture is here:

[image]

My points are a , b . I draw line between a , b

Comment: obtain the vector of values that correspond to your line first, then use diff to calculate number of transforms

Comment: can tell me how obtain vector of values that correspond to line?

Answer (score 3):

Use `improfile`:

```
c = diff(improfile(I,x,y));
```

where `x` and `y` are vectors of end point coordinates of the line. Then count nonzero elements in `c`.

Comment: thanks for your help.  improfile function is for gray and rgb image but my image is binary and the values of  improfile is 0 matrix always. is there any function like improfile for binary image?